# Can't pass NSManagedObjectContext to TableViewClass

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, appdelegate

I've got the problem to pass my managedobjectcontext to my tableviewcontroller. It doesn't with UserDefaults or with Notification. My storyboard is too big to pass it from my RootViewController:

AppDelegate:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    Schulung *first = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Schulung" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    first.name=@"testname";
    first.info=@"testinfo";
    first.location=@"testlocation";


    Abhaltungsdatum *firstDate = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Abhaltungsdatum" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    firstDate.datum = [NSDate date];
    firstDate.schulung=first;
    Abhaltungsdatum *secondDate = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Abhaltungsdatum" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    secondDate.datum=[NSDate date];
    secondDate.schulung=first;

    NSLog(@"Entities: %@",[[self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel entities]valueForKey:@"name"]);

//    NSUserDefaults *theDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.managedObjectContext];
//    [theDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"managedObjectContext"];
//    [theDefaults synchronize];
    NSNotificationCenter *theCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.managedObjectContext forKey:@"context"];
    [theCenter postNotificationName:@"managedObjectContext" object:nil userInfo:dictionary];

    return YES;
}
```

myTableViewController:

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSNotificationCenter *theCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [theCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(addManagedObjectContext:) name:@"managedObjectContext" object:nil];
//    NSUserDefaults *theDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//    NSData *data = [theDefaults objectForKey:@"managedObjectContext"];
//    self.managedObjectContext = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
//    [theDefaults synchronize];
     NSLog(@"Entities: %@",[[self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel entities]valueForKey:@"name"]);
    NSFetchRequest *theRequest = self.fetchRequest;
    NSFetchedResultsController *theController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:theRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    NSError *theError = nil;

    theController.delegate = self;
    if([theController performFetch:&theError]) {
        self.fetchedResultsController = theController;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"viewDidLoad: %@", theError);
    }
}

-(void)addManagedObjectContext:(NSNotification *)note{
    self.managedObjectContext = [[note userInfo]valueForKey:@"context"];
}
```

The NSUserDefault Object gets nil when passed and the Notification doesn't come through.

Comment: try use: YuorAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YuorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Comment: Nice that did the job. Thank you very much!!!!!! ;-)